# How to ignore value 0 during using aggregation function in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
product   | age
------------
A  | 22
B  | 0 
B  | 38
B  | 0
A  | 11
```

And I need to aggregate it by below code:

```
df.groupby("product").agg(mean_age = ("age","mean))
```

But 0 it second row definitely decrease my mean age, can I modify my above code to define that I do not want to take into consideration rows where age is 0 ?

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `replace()` for converting 0 to `NaN` then `groupby()` and aggregrate:

```
df.replace(0,float('NaN')).groupby("product").agg(mean_age = ("age","mean"))
```

OR

Filter out rows that are not 0 and then use groupby:

```
df[df['age'].ne(0)].groupby("product").agg(mean_age = ("age","mean"))
```

If needed to replace 0 to NaN for a particular column then use:

```
(df.assign(age=df['age'].replace(0,float('NaN')))
    .groupby("product").agg(mean_age = ("age","mean")))
```